KernelEvent redirect response always redirects to homepage
In my Drupal 10 project I have an event subscriber set up as follows:
final class EventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    return ['kernel.request' => ['handleKernelRequest']];
  }

  /**
   * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\KernelEvent $event
   */
  public function handleKernelRequest(KernelEvent $event) {
    // Truncated: do some regex matching, load a node...
    $url = $node->toUrl()->toAbsolute()->toString();
    $event->setResponse(new CacheableRedirectResponse($url));
  }

}

The code is being called on request to the URL I want to redirect. The response is being set correctly. The location header and a meta http-equiv="refresh" tag in the HTML content of the response are being set.
However, at some point another (core) event listener changes the content of the response to point to the homepage, but it leaves the Location HTTP header as it was.
The Redirect module is not installed. The response is the same for auth and anon users.

Update
RedirectResponseSubscriber::checkRedirectRule is overriding the redirect
    // Let the 'destination' query parameter override the redirect target.
    // If $response is already a SecuredRedirectResponse, it might reject the
    // new target as invalid, in which case proceed with the old target.
    $destination = $request->query->get('destination'); 


I found the above question myself and answered my own question 5mins before your comment, thanks!

I found the solution at: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/252877/57167

This needs to run before RouterListener::onKernelRequest(), which has a priority of 32. Otherwise, that aborts the request if no matching route is found.

Added a higher priority, and the redirect worked (after rebuilding the cache).
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
  return ['kernel.request' => ['handleKernelRequest', 34]];
}

